# How can I use XSLT with non-traditional XML formatting?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <COLLECTION>
  <RECORD>
   <FIELD fname="Description">Bike</FIELD>
   <FIELD fname="Condition">New</FIELD>
   <FIELD fname="Color">Red</FIELD>
  </RECORD>
</COLLECTION>
```

I am trying to use XSLT to format it but because its not the usual`<description>Bike</description>` formatting I'm not having much luck with the sample W3Schools code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Condition</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="COLLECTION/RECORD">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Condition"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You might like to consider that learning a programming language requires a slightly different approach than trying to generalize from a few examples on a tutorial site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sub-selectors:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="FIELD[@fname='Description']"/></td>
```

and so one.

You could also consider pre-processing the XML to a more regular format.